# Query insert query executing multiple times

Tags: wpdb

I am going through strange problem. I have defined the function in function.php inside theme directory.

### function.php

```
function db_cache($keys, $value) {
   global $wpdb;
   $value = base64_encode(serialize($value));
   $res = $wpdb->insert("db_cache", array("keys" => $keys, "value" => $value), array("%s", "%s"));
}
```

I made one wordpress template which decides which file to be included. suppose page link for given template is,

```
get_permalink(23).'?action=book_hotel'
```

In this template,

```
class func{
   function book_hotel(){
       include_once get_template_directory() . "/custom/agent/tpl-hotelbook.php";
   }
}

if($_GET['book_hotel')) {
   $obj = new func();
   $obj->book_hotel();
}
```

Again in,

### tpl-hotelbook.php

```
 db_cache("key", $value);    //when I call db_cache function insert query is executed more than once. Sometimes executes 2, and sometime query executes 3 time. what would be the problem?
```

I have checked if the function was called multiple times using `die` at last of `db_cache` function. But multiple function call was not the issues. Thank you.